How to make Vim highlight the content of a Markdown code span or code block?
When I format text either as a Markdown code span or Markdown code block, using backticks, like
```
code block
```

`code span`

then Vim highlights only the backticks, not the text inside.
For me it seems counterintuitive. The backtick is one of the smallest characters. When it comes to code blocks, the content is distinguished to some extent by tripling the backtick and the additional lines; but in case of code spans, I can barely see that the content is to be treated specially.
How can I make Vim highlight the content of a Markdown code span or code block, alongside the backticks themselves?
I have already learned that I can do
```html
<h1>text</h1>
```

and
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['html']

in .vimrc, and have the HTML syntax highlighted. Or the syntax of other languages, for that matter. That is great, I welcome Vim doing that, but this is not what I'm asking about.
Preferably I would not use any plugins; but feel free to propose a plugin-based solution if this is the only way you know of.

Update. A little clarification. The tag syntax-highlighting should refer to syntax highlighting of Markdown in general, not to syntax highlighting of Markdown code blocks or code spans.

Do you want to have syntax highlighting inside the backticks or do you just want everything inside it to be highlighted the same (e.g. like a string)?

@Friedrich, I want everything inside it to be highlighted the same. But what do you mean by "like a string"?

With "like a string" I meant that in a line of code var foo = "this is highlighted differently than the surrounding code". String is also the name of a default highlight group; romainl went with Comment in his answer.

Another thing, if you want your answer to be useful for future readers, [edit] all the clarifications in it. Turn it into a nice, concise and focused question.

OK, thanks for the explanation, I now get it. Also, thanks for the tip of editing, but it does not apply to this question, does it? I suppose all the details are already in the question, and the only, and accepted, answer is from romainl, not me.

Well, it took you six comments to make clear what you were asking about :-) Comments on this site can go away at any time (not really, but they could); questions and answers are much more permanent. So you might e.g. put your comment "The color may be the same as that of backticks already, and it should be the same color for all the text between the backticks." in your question. BTW, I agree with romainl that the excursion into HTML leads readers on the wrong track. You don't have to change anything, though.

Okay, I thought the HTML part clarifies things! Apparently it need not. If you don't mind, I'll leave it as is, I'd rather not remove anything from my questions that makes at least a little sense. As for the comment you're quoting, I don't think it applies to the question now, after I have accepted an answer. You see, I perceive a Q and A process as a dialog between the questioner and the answerers. Updating the question now should mean I have second thoughts about the answer, and I do not. But thanks again, it's a useful tip in general.

The "fenced language" notation explicitly tells whatever is responsible for highlighting what is inside the "fences" which syntax to use:
```html
<h1>text</h1>
```

without that explicit annotation, it is practically impossible to reliably infer the filetype from the content of the code block.
Since there is no "universal" way to add that kind of annotation to a "code span", then the answer is no.
---EDIT---
After clarification by OP…
Syntax highlighting is done by attributing so-called "highlight groups" to various parts of the text in the buffer. Those highlight groups are supposed to be "linked" to default highlight groups like Statement or Constant. If a highlight group is not explicitly linked to a default group, then it is treated by Vim as the Normal highlight group, which is used for normal text.
The built-in syntax script for markdown assigns the markdownCode highlight group to the text between backticks.
markdownCode is not linked to any default highlight groups by default so there is no special highlighting for text between backticks.
If you want that text to be highlighted, you can…

Choose a highlight group from :help group-name and :help highlight-groups.

Link markdownCode to that highlight group in the command-line:
:hi link markdownCode Comment

Experiment with various groups until you are satisfied.

Follow the instructions under :help colorscheme-override to persist your override between sessions.



Thanks for the answer! I believe either you misunderstand my question, or I your answer. I'd like to have highlighted any text that is between backticks, not any particular syntax that this text might have.

PS Oh, maybe the syntax-highlighting tag is misleading! I thought it should refer to syntax highlighting of Markdown in general, not syntax highlighting of Markdown code blocks or code spans. Should I change or remove it?

Well, what kind of highlighting do you want between those backticks? Syntax-aware highlighting like with fenced code blocks or just one vaguely random color for the whole thing? If the latter, then mentioning fenced code blocks is unnecessary noise. All you need is to link markdownCode to another highlight group, like hi link markdownCode Comment. See :help colorscheme-override.

romainl, I want to highlight the text between backticks. No more, no less. The color may be the same as that of backticks already, and it should be the same color for all the text between the backticks. I should think it is more of the latter of what you said, but I don't see why it should be unnecessary noise. Beyond code spans, I'm precisely referring to the color of text in code blocks, or "fenced code blocks" if we assume they are the same thing.

PS So, I think your solution involving markdownCode may apply, but I need to read more about it as I don't see yet how it can help me.

PS2 Yes, I've just tested, the highlight link command does exactly what I want. Will you post a new answer yourself, or should I do it?

I edited my answer.
